# What uncertainties to use when fitting a distribution model to binned sample data?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, curve-fitting, uncertainty

A common task is to fit to a sample of $N$ data $x_i$ (assumed 1D for the sake of argument) a model $p(x|a)$ (normalized to unit integral) for their distribution with some parameters $a$. One way is to maximise the log-likelihood
$$
L(a) = \sum_i \ln p(x_i|a),
$$
possibly combined with a prior for the parameters. But more frequent and more convenient is a fit to the histogram $n_k$ obtained by binning the data into bins of some width $h$ at locations $X_k$. In this case, one usually fits the model by minimizing
$$
\chi^2(a) = \sum_k \frac{[n_k-NP_k]^2}{\sigma_k^2},
$$
where $P_k=\int_{X_k-h}^{X_k+h}p(x|a)\mathrm{d}x$ is the model prediction for the probability to find a datum in the $k$th bin.

**What is the appropriate choice for $\sigma_k$?**

All packages implementing a $\chi^2$ fit that I have come across (such as `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`) require input for $\sigma_k$, when a natural choice are the **estimates** $$\sigma_k\approx\sqrt{n_k}.$$ However, since the data are random, so are these estimates implying they have **errors**. As example consider an empty bin ($n_k=0$), when this choice enforces $P_k=0$.

These errors can be avoided by using the **predictions** $$\sigma_k=\sqrt{NP_k}$$ from the model. In this case an empty bin can be accommodated by a small $P_k$. As these prediction cannot be provided a priory, but require knowledge of the model, they cannot be implemented with most fitting packages.

So, why does apparently nobody use this latter form?

Comment: Why do binning at all?

Comment: for example to visualize the data (together with the best fitting $p(x)$)

Comment: 1) You might find yourself preferring KDEs to histograms; KDEs do not do binning (maybe you can force it with an unusual kernel, but not with the defaults in standard software packages). // 2) Fitting a distribution to the data is different from visualizing the data. You can visualize a histogram yet use unbinned data for the distribution fit.

Comment: @Dave thanks for that suggestion. Yes I do that too. But I want to measure a certain property of the distribution and its significance. For that I thought to fit a model with the corresponding feature in parameterised form.

Comment: I don't see how that affects whether or not you should do binning. // You might consider posting a new question where you ask about the real problem you have. It is common for statistics practitioners to ask "XY" problems where they have problem X and think they can solve X with solution Y, but they don't fully understand solution Y, so they ask about Y instead of their real question X. As an example, I recently asked my dad to help me pick out a ladder. "Why?" "I need to squash bugs on the ceiling." "Oh, then I have a bug squasher pole I can get you." I never cared about getting a ladder.